# "Critical in" vs. "critical for" vs. "critical to"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, to-for

I am confused about the correct preposition to use before *achieving* in this sentence:

> Tracking service delivery is critical in achieving the goals of the health program.

I feel "critical for achieving" or "cricial to achieving" sounds better.

Comment: Have you done any research? Googling '  "critical for achieving" ', for example? When you've reported back, I'm sure you'll get some further discussions - this does not seem all that straightforward a question.

Comment: Please forget about *critical* and focus on the preposition: which of them you mean. For example, does the context refer to something *in achieving*? Or *to achieving*? Or *for achieving*? Do not be carried away by collocation examples from literature.

Answer (score 3):

"Critical to" is usually apt when it preceds a noun

For e.g. critical to the Health Program Certification

"Critical for" is usually apt when "joining" parts

For e.g. Studying is critical for him to gain good grades in his school

"Critical in" usually preceds a verb . This is the example you have used

Comment: This sounds good, John, and may well be true. But have you any authority to support your claims?

Answer (score 0):

I find all three acceptable, to the degree that I don't know which of the three I would use myself.